# Grothendieck Group for General Monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

Is there an analog to Grothendieck group for general monoids?

I imagine such thing could be constructed but I have not found this construction in standard text so I am not sure if it makes sense. (Or maybe my searching ability is not good enough.)

My idea is as follows. Suppose $M$ is a monoid. Let $M^{-1}$ be another monoid isomorphic to $M$ and let $\varphi:M \to M^{-1}$ be the isomorphism between them. Form the free product $M * M^{-1}$ and define a congruence relation $R$ on $M * M^{-1}$ by equations $m\varphi(m) = 1 = \varphi(m)m$ for $m \in M$, where $1$ is the identity of $M * M^{-1}$, $M$ and $M^{-1}$. $N = (M * M^{-1})/R$ is the desired result.

For $m \in M \cup M^{-1}$ (considering $1$ as the only element in $M \cap M^{-1}$), let $m^{-1} = \varphi(m)$ if $m \in M$ and $m^{-1} = \varphi^{-1}(m)$ if $m \in M^{-1}$. Every element $m$ of $M \oplus M^{-1}$ can be written as a finite product $m = m_1 \ldots m_n$ with $m_i \in M \cup M^{-1}$. Define $m^{-1} = m_n^{-1} \ldots m_1^{-1}$. Then $mm^{-1} \equiv m^{-1}m \equiv 1 \pmod R$, so $N$ is a group.

Suppose $\theta: M \to N$ is the homomorphism $M \to M * M^{-1} \xrightarrow{\text{mod } R} N$. I would expect that this is universal in the sense that every monoid morphism $\psi: M \to P$ with $P$ a group factors through $\theta$. Is this the case? Are there any problems with this construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine.

The fact that a monoid morphism $\psi: M\to P$ to a group factors *uniquely* through $\theta$ (the uniqueness is very important!) is fairly easy to prove from first principles, but it should be abstractly intuitive as well.  The point is that we've just taken $M$, freely adjoined a symbol $m_-$ for each $m\in M$, and taken the quotient by the relations $mm_-=m_- m=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's very intuitive too. I just need confirmation. It surprises me a little bit why Grothendieck groups are only discussed for commutative cancellative monoids. I believe $\theta$ would be injective if $M$ is cancellative, but that is a little less intuitive the more I think about it.

Comment: Oh, let me add a small nitpick: I really dislike the notation $\oplus$ for the free product.  Categorically, it's a good analogy (it's the binary coproduct, after all), but it's likely to confuse some people.

Comment: Aah. I wasn't sure what to use there. I guess a more appropriate symbol is probably $\amalg$, right?

Comment: @Tunococ I'd use $\coprod$ in a categorical setting, $*$ for groups, monoids, etc.

Comment: @Tunococ By the way, I'm not sure what the connection is precisely, but I know the "Grothendieck group" as something associated to an abelian category (more generally, an exact category).  For example, the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces with the operation $\oplus$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, and its Grothendieck group is $\mathbb{Z}$.  I'm not sure if this point of view applies to arbitrary commutative monoids, but it does require some kind of abelian-ness.  The commutativity restriction probably has to do with the K-theory origins, not mathematical restrictions.

Comment: I believe there are two different things that are referred to as "Grothendieck group".

Comment: @Tunococ What I'm saying is that the one for commutative monoids is a special case of the other one.  I think I've worked out the details: if $M$ is a commutative monoid, we let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of finitely generated free $M$-sets equipped with a distinguished element.  Then $\mathcal{C}$ is an abelian (exact?) category, and the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to the "universal group" containing $M$.

Comment: @Tunococ The point is that commutativity is not really important, it's just that the non-commutative version isn't a "Grothendieck group".

Comment: That explains why this "universal group" construction has not been given the term "Grothendieck group". [Sources from the internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) seem to focus on the wrong thing. I now understand that Grothendieck groups are assumed abelian from the definition. Thank you for your help.